# Python. Pegar uma substring em um texto formatado

Tags: python, eclipse

Olá.

Eu tenho uma string formatada com vários atributos, preciso pegar todos os campos "text". Neste exemplo, preciso pegar "Gmail" e "Youtube" e descartar todo o resto. Usando Python

```
<node bounds="{0, 0, 540, 36}" 
checked="false" 
class="android.widget.FrameLayout" 
clickable="false" 
enabled="true" 
id="" 
index="1" 
indexId="-1" 
long-clickable="false" 
package="com.android.systemui" 
password="false" 
resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/hided_by_cover_group2" 
scrollable="false" 
selected="false" 
stringname="" 
talkback="" 
text="" 
><node bounds="{0, 0, 540, 36}" 
checked="false" 
class="android.widget.FrameLayout" 
clickable="false" 
enabled="true" 
id="" 
index="2" 
indexId="-1" 
long-clickable="false" 
package="com.android.systemui" 
password="false" 
resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/msim_panel_holder" 
scrollable="false" 
selected="false" 
stringname="" 
talkback="Gmail" 
text="Gmail" 
></node>

<node bounds="{0, 0, 540, 36}" 
checked="false" 
class="android.widget.FrameLayout" 
clickable="false" 
enabled="true" 
id="" 
index="1" 
indexId="-1" 
long-clickable="false" 
package="com.android.systemui" 
password="false" 
resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/hided_by_cover_group2" 
scrollable="false" 
selected="false" 
stringname="" 
talkback="" 
text="" 
><node bounds="{0, 0, 540, 36}" 
checked="false" 
class="android.widget.FrameLayout" 
clickable="false" 
enabled="true" 
id="" 
index="2" 
indexId="-1" 
long-clickable="false" 
package="com.android.systemui" 
password="false" 
resource-id="com.android.systemui:id/msim_panel_holder" 
scrollable="false" 
selected="false" 
stringname="" 
talkback="Youtube" 
text="Youtube" 
></node>
```

Thank you

Comment: Alterado para Portugues. Alguém sabe responder?

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de ser um exemplo simples de se pegar os dados ou filtrando-se as linhas
ou usando-se expressões regulares - como o texto é um XML válido, a recomendação é usar as ferramentas de XML para se pegar os valores desejados.

Dessa forma, se em algum ponto futuro, a formatação "externa" do arquivo muda,
ou se você precisar de outros campos, o código continua válido -  além do que XML tem algumas outras características que seriam válidas nos dados de entrada, e que a leitura como texto simples simplesmente descartaria (uso de  entidades como nomes de caractéres, etc...).

Agora - seu XML está mal-formatado - ou por que você não colou o arquivo todo, ou porque o editou a mão - perceba que no trecho dado, não há um elemento "raiz" que é pai de todos os outros, e alguns dos `node` não tem a tag de fechamento.
Com um xml bem-formado, que esteja na variável de nome "texto" pode-se fazer:

```
from xml.elementtree import ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring(texto.strip())
atributos = [element.get("text") for element in xml.iter() if element.tag=="node" and element.get("text", None)]
```

A primeira linha importa a classe de Python ElementTree para trabalhar com XML.
A segunda, constrói um objeto XML "vivo" usando a string formatada (o método "parse" em vez de "fromstring" pode ler um arquivo diretamente). A terceira linha usa um list comprehension - um  `for` inline do Python para visitar todos os elementos do seu XML, e se a tag for `node` e houver algum conteúdo no atributo `text` esse é usado como parte da lista. Ao final, a variável "atributos" vai ter tudo o que estaria em qualquer elemento "text" nessa estrutura